# Regex ruby syntax to select a number while excluding specific ones

Tags: ruby, regex

I am still struggling to find some ruby regex syntax despite the numerous documentation on-line. I have an array of string and I am looking for strings that include one number (whatever the number of digits) but not specific one (let's say for instance dates from 19XX to 201X).

I manage to get the regex for "the line contain a number"

```
.*\p{N}.*
```

I manage to get "exclude the line if this number is a year"

```
(?!19\d\d|20[0-1]\d)\d{4}
```

But I fail to combine both. I would need something that would intuitively be written as such

```
(.*\p{N}.*)&&(?!19\d\d|20[0-1]\d)\d{4}
```

But I am not sure how an AND operator can be used.

Comment: You can use a mere `/\A(?!.*\b(?:19\d\d|20[01]\d)\b).*\d/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
^(?!.*19\d\d.*)(?!.*20[01]\d.*)(.*\p{N}.*)$
```

You want a string that:

- `(?!.*19\d\d.*)` doesn't contains 19xx
- `(?!.*20[01]\d.*)` doesn't contains 200x or 201x
- `(.*\p{N}+.*)` contains, *at least*, one digit

In regex `&&` means, well, literal `&&` and not `and` operator

---

If you want to capture numbers that are not in the range `1900-2019` you can replace with:

```
(?!\b19\d\d\b)(?!\b20[01]\d\b)(\b\p{N}+\b)
```

You can test it [here](http://rubular.com/r/n5akDQN7Lg)

Answer (score 0):

While the solution by Thomas is probably the best one, another option would be to go without negation: just select everything, that matches:

```
re = /\D(
  [03-9]\d*|
  (?:1|2|20)(?=\D)|
  1[0-8]\d*|
  19\d?(?=\D)|
  19\d{3,}|
  20[2-9]\d*|
  20[01]?(?=\D)|
  20[01]\d{2,}
)/x

▶ 'Here 2014 and 1945 and 1878 and 20000 and 2 and 19 and 195 and 203'.scan re
#⇒ [["1878"], ["20000"], ["2"], ["19"], ["195"], ["203"]]
```